# attribute name of object need to be variable

Tags: twig

I have an Object `User` has many attributes

```
  User.name
  User.email
  User.mobile
  User.falg
```

I need to access this attributes by for loop , something like that

```
{% set attrs = ['email','mobile','name',  .... etc] %}
{% for (attr in attrs) %}
    {{ user.attr }}
{% endfor %}
```

How can id that ?

Comment: `{% for attribute, value in user %} ... {% endfor %}`

Comment: Or if you to want limit it with the `attrs` array you need to change `{{ user.attr }}` to `{{ user[attr] }}`

Comment: Thanks! ... it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use [attribute](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) function for your case